Energy transfer in Transformers
Is magnetic energy being transferred to the secondary coil in a transformer? And does that mean that if the secondary coil is not present, the energy which would've been transferred to the secondary coil will be just stored as magnetic energy just as in a pure inductive AC circuit?

No energy is transferred from the primary to the secondary of a transformer unless the secondary is delivering current to a load.

A transformer with a primary winding only is an iron-core inductor in which energy is stored in the magnetic field in the core so long as there is current flow to sustain the field.

Does that mean that when a secondary coil is present, no energy is stored in the primary coil's magnetic field as potential energy?

@User314159, both coils store energy in their fields.
